# Laravel destroy won't delete data from database

Tags: laravel-5.4, eloquent

Trying to delete an entry from database using the following in Laravel 5.4 without success.

**My View**

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['faculty.delete', $faculty->id]]) !!}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**My Route**

```
Route::delete('faculty/delete/{id}', 'FacultyController@destroy')->name('faculty.delete');//delete faculty
```

**My Controller**

```
public function destroy(Faculty $faculty)
{
    //Log::info($faculty);
    $faculty->delete();
    return redirect('faculties/faculty');
}
```

The `log` in the controller returns an empty value when I allow it to run.

The problem is that the code does not delete the item from the table.

Comment: Does the form redirect you to facultes/faculty?

Comment: Yes, it does. There are no errors at all.

Comment: You need to change faculty/delete/{id} to faculty/delete/{faculty}

Comment: Thanks, man. It worked so well.

Comment: No problem, if you could accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `faculty/delete/{id}` to `faculty/delete/{faculty}`.

Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route segment name.

Since the `$faculty` variable is type-hinted as the `App\Faculty` Eloquent model and the variable name matches the `{faculty}` URI segment, Laravel will automatically inject the model instance that has an ID matching the corresponding value from the request URI. If a matching model instance is not found in the database, a 404 HTTP response will automatically be generated.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding